# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT not working properly in android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
```

not showing files images from camera and downloaded images are shown as not selectable.